# Multiagent in Python using Spade localhost configuration issue

Tags: python, agent-based-modeling, multi-agent

I want to try Multi Agent programming in Python using SPADE, but i can't seem to make this simple example work. The error refers to the server, so how can i set up the agents to work in the localhost ?

here is my code :

```
class SenderAgent(Agent):
    class InformBehav(OneShotBehaviour):
        async def run(self):
            print("InformBehav running")
            msg = Message(to="receiveragent@127.0.0.1")     # Instantiate the message
            msg.set_metadata("performative", "inform")  # Set the "inform" FIPA performative
            msg.body = "Hello World"                    # Set the message content

            await self.send(msg)
            print("Message sent!")

            # stop agent from behaviour
            await self.agent.stop()

    async def setup(self):
        print("SenderAgent started")
        b = self.InformBehav()
        self.add_behaviour(b)

class ReceiverAgent(Agent):
    class RecvBehav(OneShotBehaviour):
        async def run(self):
            print("RecvBehav running")

            msg = await self.receive(timeout=10) # wait for a message for 10 seconds
            if msg:
                print("Message received with content: {}".format(msg.body))
            else:
                print("Did not received any message after 10 seconds")

            # stop agent from behaviour
            await self.agent.stop()

    async def setup(self):
        print("ReceiverAgent started")
        b = self.RecvBehav()
        template = Template()
        template.set_metadata("performative", "inform")
        self.add_behaviour(b, template)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    receiveragent = ReceiverAgent("receiveragent@127.0.0.1", '1234')
    future = receiveragent.start()
    future.result() # wait for receiver agent to be prepared.
    senderagent = SenderAgent("senderagent@127.0.0.1", '1234')
    senderagent.start()

    while receiveragent.is_alive():
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            senderagent.stop()
            receiveragent.stop()
            break
    print("Agents finished")
```

as i'm getting the following errors :

```
connection failed: [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 5222)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrateur/PycharmProjects/spade/test.py", line 53, in <module>
    future.result() # wait for receiver agent to be prepared.
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 435, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spade\agent.py", line 100, in _async_start
    await self._async_register()
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spade\agent.py", line 142, in _async_register
    _, stream, features = await aioxmpp.node.connect_xmlstream(self.jid, metadata, loop=self.loop)
  File "C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\aioxmpp\node.py", line 415, in connect_xmlstream
    exceptions
aioxmpp.errors.MultiOSError: failed to connect to XMPP domain '127.0.0.1': multiple errors: [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 5222)
```